# How to properly use Thread.yield() method in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, yield

I have a class that will use yield every time a loop iterates 10 times. I read in the Java API that using yield may require "detailed profiling and benchmarking to ensure that it actually has the desired effect". I am wondering if my yield implementation is correct, or will my yield implementation have no effect whatsoever if more then one of these threads are running. Here is the code:

```
public class FindIt extends Thread{

  private int num;
  private int begin;
  private int end;

/**
 * Class constructor.
 * @param num
 * @param begin
 * @param end
 */
  FindIt(int num, int begin, int end){
    this.num = num;
    this.begin = begin;
    this.end = end;
  }

/**
 * This search method searches within the threads given interval for a number.
 */
  public void search(){
    for(int i = this.begin; i <= this.end; i++){
      if( i % 10 == 0){
        this.yield();

      }
      if (i == this.num){
        System.out.println(num + " was found by thread: "+ this.getName()); 
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Require extra _what_?

Comment: "detailed profiling and benchmarking to ensure that it actually has the desired effect."

Answer (score 2):

The `yield` method simply tells to the Java thread scheduler that the current thread is willing to take some rest and thus give some CPU time to other threads to do some work. As far as I know, this method was mostly useful in the old days when there were machines with a single CPU running a multi-threaded Java program. As the JavaDoc of this method says it's rarely appropriate to use this method (at least as of today). Not sure but maybe you just misunderstood the functionality behind this method.

See also [Preemption / Time Slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_%28computing%29) which are somewhat related concepts.

Comment: *As far as I know, this method was mostly useful in the old days...* `ForkJoinPool` is _by far_ not implemented in that era - and it still uses `Thread::yield`

Answer (score 0):

Thread.yield is a hint to the scheduler so it may not do what you want. I might consider using Object.wait(0,1) instead which will wait for the minimal amount of time